# Inhibiting `finished:` message from `async-shell-command`

Tags: shell-command, message

Running `(async-shell-command "echo test")` prints `echo test: finished` to the echo area upon completion. I am running a function in the background on a loop with a special handler, and the message is just distracting for me. How can I programmatically disable it for this invocation?

Normally I would do this with a local `(let ((inhibit-message t)) …)`, but this is presumably happening in a continuation somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two versions of function `(inhibit-sentinel-messages FUN &rest ARGS)` defined in Section *Code of inhibit-sentinel-messages* of this answer. The first version wraps all sentinels started in `FUN` with `set-process-sentinel` into `let` blocks with `inhibit-message t`. The second version avoids sentinel messages completely by temporarily advising `message` with `ignore`.

You can use `inhibit-sentinel-messages` like so:

```el
(inhibit-sentinel-messages #'async-shell-command "echo test")
```

If you also want to hide the `*Async Shell Command*` buffer you can use `display-buffer-alist` let-bound as follows:

```el
(let ((display-buffer-alist (cons '("\\`\\*Async Shell Command\\*\\'" display-buffer-no-window) display-buffer-alist)))
  (inhibit-sentinel-messages #'async-shell-command "echo test"))
```

If you want to suppress sentinel messages in idle timers you need to use `inhibit-sentinel-messages` in the body of the timer function.

Example:

```el
(setq my-counter 0)

(setq my-timer (run-with-idle-timer
        10 t
        (lambda ()
          (inhibit-sentinel-messages
           #'async-shell-command (format "echo test%d" (cl-incf my-counter))))))
```

### Code of `inhibit-sentinel-messages`

#### Binding `inhibit-message` to `t`

This code avoids displaying the sentinel messages in the echo area. The sentinel messages are still output to the `*Messages*` buffer.

```el
(defun inhibit-sentinel-messages (fun &rest args)
  "Inhibit messages in all sentinels started by fun."
  (cl-letf* ((old-set-process-sentinel (symbol-function 'set-process-sentinel))
         ((symbol-function 'set-process-sentinel)
          (lambda (process sentinel)
        (funcall
         old-set-process-sentinel
         process
         `(lambda (&rest args)
            (let ((inhibit-message t))
              (apply (quote ,sentinel) args)))))))
        (apply fun args)))
```

#### Temporarily advising `message` to `ignore`

This code avoids the generation of sentinel messages completely.

```el
(defun inhibit-sentinel-messages (fun &rest args)
  "Inhibit messages in all sentinels started by fun."
  (cl-letf* ((old-set-process-sentinel (symbol-function 'set-process-sentinel))
         ((symbol-function 'set-process-sentinel)
          (lambda (process sentinel)
        (funcall
         old-set-process-sentinel
         process
         `(lambda (&rest args)
            (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'message) #'ignore))
              (apply (quote ,sentinel) args)))))))
        (apply fun args)))
```

Comment: This looks very promising, and indeed if I run `(inhibit-sentinel-messages #'async-shell-command "echo test")` it does not echo a `finished` message. However, if I run it in the background on a loop, it gives me `finished` messages again. Maybe there's a problem with repeated processes? Or perhaps something conflicting with idle timers?

Comment: Maybe it would be more reliable—if more dangerous—to simply filter the `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: @MatthewPiziak `inhibit-sentinel-messages` works for me also in timer functions (with Emacs 26.1). I've added a usage example for an idle timer in the answer. I have also added another version of `inhibit-sentinel-messages` that avoids not only the display in the echo area but also the output in the message buffer.

Comment: This works! Totally my fault. I had an extra `(shell-command-sentinel process signal)` in my handler for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This message is coming from the `shell-command-sentinel` function in simple.el.  A nasty way of doing what you want would be to simply redefine the function like this:

```
(defun shell-command-sentinel (process signal)
  (when (memq (process-status process) '(exit signal))
    (shell-command--set-point-after-cmd (process-buffer process))))
```

which just removes the call to `message`, but would of course prevent the message from appearing with all shell commands.  Obviously you could use a global variable to determine whether or not to suppress the message, but I don't know how you could tell when all of your asynchronous commands have finished running...